# Installed a new NVidia graphics card and now I can't login

Tags: linux, linux-mint, graphics, nvidia

Running Linux Mint 14, I was using the integrated graphics from the i5 4670k processor. Now I've installed a NVidia graphics card (GTX 660 Ti) and now it doesn't login on normal mode.

I tried *recovery mode*, logged in and installed nvidia-current. After reboot, now the recovery mode does no longer work...

Guess I'll have to login using a live cd, but I don't know what I should fix. Any clues?

More info:

- Neither in recovery mode nor in normal mode was I able to jump to a TTY.
- There was no `xorg.conf`, that's the first thing I checked from the live cd.
- By *"does no longer work"* I meant that it gets stuck at the last message, and does not jump to a shell or anything like that.

Anyways, I eventually gave up and reinstalled Linux Mint. I was also forced to manually disable the integrated graphics card from the BIOS for the new installation to work, even though Windows, for instance, was able to detect what graphics card the screen was connected to.

Comment: Please explain some more. What do you mean the recovery mode does not work? What do you see? Can you get to a tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1? Do you have an `xorg.conf` file?

Comment: What does 'doesn't login' mean. Does X start, is there just a blank screen, does your keyboard react on input (Ctrl+Alt+F1 or switching NumLock)? What happens if you remove the card again (assuming you still have the old drivers installed)?